# Duplicate radio button group in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with some javascript code and was wondering if someone could help. I am working on the registration form, in particular the "Register someone else" part. I have the code working pretty good, except when I try to duplicate radio button groups in the javascript, it doesn't seem to want to change the group name attribute.

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add').click(function() {
    $('<div class="container_add_registrant" >
    <p class="text_content">First name:<br /><input type="text" name="add_registrant[][fname]" id="add_registrant[][fname]" /></p>
    <p class="text_content">Last name:<br /><input type="text" name="add_registrant[][lname]" id="add_registrant[][lname]" /></p>
    <p class="text_content">Workout option: <?php get_event_options_additional($event_id); ?></p>

    <p class="text_content">Shirt size:<input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="S" id="S" />S&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="M" id="M" />M&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="L" id="L" />L&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="XL" id="XL" />XL</p>

    <p class="text_content">Is this person a cancer survivor?:<input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][survivor]" value="Y" id="Y" />Yes <input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][survivor]" value="N" id="N" />No </p></div>')
    .fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.add_registrant');

    i++;
    });

    $('#remove').click(function() {
        if(i > 0) {
            $('.container_add_registrant:last').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });

});

 </script>
```

This part of the code seems to be the problem:

```
<p class="text_content">Shirt size:
   <input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="S" id="S" />S&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="M" id="M" />M&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="L" id="L" />L&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]" value="XL" id="XL" />XL
</p>
```

Here is the fiddle url again (sorry, first time using this site)

http://jsfiddle.net/4qaaN/1/

Click "register someone else" at least 2 times and you'll see the problem I'm getting with the radio buttons

Comment: where is the 'Register someone else' thingy there?

Comment: I do not see "register someone else" in this fiddle.

Comment: I don't see how the posted code touches any radio buttons.

Comment: BTW: Showing your server-side PHP code does nothing to help solve a client-side problem.

Comment: I just fixed the fiddle url, that should explain my problem better than i could above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already keeping a count of how many new registrants there are with `i`, you can just put that in the name at runtime to separate them out. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4qaaN/2/).

Essentially, it's just

```
'<input type="radio" name="add_registrant[][shirtsize]' + i + '" value="S" id="S" />'
```

`i` can be on either side, whatever you prefer for parsing it out server side.

Comment: I suspected i could do something with the i variable, but wasn't sure how to write it into the code since i am very new writing javascript.

Comment: I know it's been 4 years and you haven't posted in that time but if you ever log on again, please accept this answer if it solved your problem.